# Drupal 7 Update Manager not working

Tags: updating

Update manager takes me to the page where I select the checkbox for the updates I need. I check the box of the module and then it downloads the update. After the download it tells me I should put my site in maintenance mode with a checkbox that is on by default. The button says "Continue" to install the updated module.

My problem lies after this point. No updates are installed and after clicking "Continue" I get booted to my home page with the message "Operating in maintenance mode. Go online."

So currently the only way to update my modules is manually. Update manager doesn't work for me. Any pointers as to why it behaves the way it does?

Comment: The update manager won't automatically update modules that have a beta release.

Comment: This question is a year old; are you still experiencing this problem? FWIW, of my 30+ sites I manage I don't have this problem. Had I experienced it, I'd first confirm permissions are correct and check my error log for clues.

Comment: This question is unfortunately a poor fit for the Q+A format used at this site. This is not how this feature normally behaves. It looks as if there is something at your site that stops this from working. Without having direct access to the site with debugging tools, it impossible to narrow it down to pin down the cause. When you're further along in your debugging and have specific questions then please do ask them. Please see the [FAQ](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic) for more information about what kinds if questions can be asked here.

Comment: I figured it out. The module was a beta.

Answer (score 0):

Does yoursitename.something/update.php runs after you put it your browser location.
I can only guess maybe your site hosting space is full or you might not have given update permission to the role by which you are updating the site.